# R - using sapply for a personalized function

Tags: r

I'm creating a dummy variable - 1 if previous row has the same Species, 0 otherwise.

I'm using this to learn the apply functions.

I can do it for the entire set, but not for a specified vector.

Here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
sapply(iris$Species, function(x)ifelse(x==lag(x,1),1,0))
```

It returns a list of NA.

Note: removing $Species returns correct values for the whole set

I know there are faster ways to do this (found below), I'm just trying to learn the apply functions.

```
index = which(iris$Species==lag(iris$Species,1))
same = rep(0,nrow(test))
same[index] = 1
iris[,'test'] = same
```

Comment: `sapply` is not the right function here, you can just do `as.numeric(iris$Species == dplyr::lag(iris$Species))`

Comment: `sapply` will act on each element of the column as if it is a scalar. So, the arguement to `lag` will only be one element which will return `NA`